# Table of contents page number indenting/ alignment

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, texmaker, tocloft

As per the photo below, I'm having a problem with the alignment of the page numbers in the table of contents. Specifically, when using `\addcontentsline` to add an entry to the ToC that exists in the front matter, the roman numerals indicating the page don't align with the page numbers of section in the main matter part of the document.

[image]

Here's a MWE I put together that demonstrates both my Latex code and the problem. Any help in fixing would be much appreciated!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% Redefine TOC stuff
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip10pt}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip15pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsubsecdotsep}}

% Front matter, main matter, back matter definitions
\makeatletter
\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  %\@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
 % \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage[a4paper,%
            left=20mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\section*{Executive Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Executive Summary}
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\section{Test Section 1}
\subsection{Test Subsection 1.1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is aligned see [this version if I change the page numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sibMS.png) it's just the relatively large foot of the 1 that gives the appearance.That said you might want to add some negative space to make it look more visually aligned....

Comment: Good point! How would I go about adding negative space? Thanks!